# Lie Algebra of Bivariate L2 Functions

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $L^2$ be the vector space of bivariate, square-normable functions, i.e., $L^2 := \{ f(x,y) | \iint_{[0,1]^2}dxdy|f(x)|^2 < \infty \}$.
And let the Poisson bracket be defined on $L^2$ as $\{f, g\} := \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$.

Since the Poisson bracket satisfies bilinearity, alternativity ($\{f, f\}=0$), and the Jacobi identity, it is clear that $L^2$ equipped with $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ forms a Lie algebra.
My question is, can one identify a Lie group whose Lie algebra is isomorphic to $L^2$?

Since $L^2$ is clearly infinite-dimensional, it is clear that Lie's third theorem does not apply.
Not being familiar with the Lie theory that much, I'm not sure what kind of conditions I should look for in this case.

Thank you.

Comment: $\{ \cdot, \cdot \}$ is not defined on the whole $L^2$. Even if you restrict the domain to the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}$, you still have the question that there might be $f,g \in W^{1,2}$ but $\{f,g\} \in L^1 \backslash W^{1,2}$.

Comment: @Zerox Hmm, that's a good point. Thank you for the comment. What if I give up the completeness and restrict to the $C_\infty$ space? Would it form a valid Lie algebra then?